# OcLazyLoader path is not working controller is not loading

Tags: angularjs, oclazyload, session-state-provider

I am trying to load js and css when corresponding state has reached
i am isunf OcLazyLoader and 
i have mentioned controller name and i am trying to load controller defintion using ocloader but i am getting controller undefined

My config file is

```js
   .state('menu.table', {
            url: '/table',
            controller: 'tableController',
            templateUrl: 'module/table/table.html',
            resolve :{
                loadMyCtrl : ['$ocLazyLoad',function($ocLazyLoad){
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name:"smartExpenseApp.tableController",
                        files:["module/table/js/table.js"]
                    });
                }
                    
                ]
            }
        })
```

and 
My table.js s

```js
smartExpenseApp.controller('tableController',function ($scope, $log) {
    $scope.names = [
        {
            name: 'Jani'
            , country: 'Norway'
        }
        , {
            name: 'Carl'
            , country: 'Sweden'
        }
        , {
            name: 'Margareth'
            , country: 'England'
        }
        , {
            name: 'Hege'
            , country: 'Norway'
        }
        , {
            name: 'Joe'
            , country: 'Denmark'
        }
        , {
            name: 'Gustav'
            , country: 'Sweden'
        }
        , {
            name: 'Birgit'
            , country: 'Denmark'
        }
        , {
            name: 'Mary'
            , country: 'England'
        }
        , {
            name: 'Kai'
            , country: 'Norway'
        }
  ];

    $scope.sortField = "name";
    $scope.sortBy = false;
    $scope.sortColumn = function (column) {
        $scope.sortField = column;
        $scope.sortBy = $scope.sortField == (column) ? !$scope.sortBy : false;

    }
    $scope.getSortClass = function (column) {
        if ($scope.sortField == column) {
            return $scope.sortBy ? "glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom" : "glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top";
        }

        return 'glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign';
    }
});
```

Please help in this issue because i am getting

```html
angular.js:13424 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'tableController' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/ng/areq?p0=tableController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at file:///F:/Workspace/Angular/Smart%20Expense/SmartExpense-WEB/Example/common/resources/Angular/Angular/angular.js:68:12
    at assertArg (file:///F:/Workspace/Angular/Smart%20Expense/SmartExpense-WEB/Example/common/resources/Angular/Angular/angular.js:1844:11)
    at assertArgFn (file:///F:/Workspace/Angular/Smart%20Expense/SmartExpense-WEB/Example/common/resources/Angular/Angular/angular.js:1854:3)
```